# What is the difference between "asymmetric key cryptosystem" "asymmetric cryptography" terminology?

Tags: public-key, terminology

What is the difference between "asymmetric cryptography" and "asymmetric key cryptosystem"  terminology?

Comment: The first is the general technology, the second a more concrete use case where these technologies get applied in a specific way. See [Wikipedia: Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptosystem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic definitions from Wikipedia.

> **[Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography)** or cryptology is the practice and study of techniques for secure communication in the presence of third parties called adversaries.
>
> In cryptography, a **[cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptosystem)** is a suite of cryptographic algorithms needed to implement a particular security service, most commonly for achieving confidentiality (encryption)
>
> [**Public-key cryptography**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), or **asymmetric cryptography**, is a cryptographic system that uses pairs of keys: public keys which may be disseminated widely, and private keys which are known only to the owner.

**Asymmetric Cryptography** is the general technology to study techniques for securing communication with public-key Cryptography. Eg. public-key encryption, digital signatures.

**Asymmetric Key Cryptosystem** is the suite of asymmetric cryptographic algorithms applied. Eg. RSA, ECC.

Answer (score 1):

‘Cryptosystem’ refers to a more specific thing, like the RSAES-OAEP cryptosystem.  ‘Cryptography’ refers more generally to the field of study, or to the collection of tools.

If you're reading a particular source on the subject, and it seems to be drawing a finer distinction that this doesn't illuminate, you'll need to share the original source.